# UDP issues on android version

Tags: android, flutter, udp

I want to control my Wiz light bulbs without using the closed source package. There is a connector for it available (https://pub.dev/packages/wiz).

The application is based on the example provided by the package (https://pub.dev/packages/wiz/example) and it runs smoothly on my development environment (linux). When I use my android device as debug environment (connected with USB-cable), it works as well!

But, when I build apk-files (with `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`) and test it on my android device, it doesn't work.

When starting the application, you need to push a "sync" button. It starts a udp-broadcast on the local network to try to find the light bulbs IP-adress. On my linux laptop, that takes a second or two and it shows spinning arrows to show it is doing somehting. When lights are found, buttons get available to adjust them (intensity, temperature, ...).

On the android device, when I push the sync button, it doesn't find any device. I barely see spinning arrows.

The first 6 lines of `AndroidManifest.xml` is:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <application..
```

I've only few experiences with android development and flutter, but to me it seems that the udp broadcast OR the receiving of responses goes wrong. But why does it work when using the `app-debug.pkg` version of it (I see this is build when using my android device as debug environment)?

Edit:
The method for finding devices that must be used from library Wiz is: https://github.com/AYJF/wiz/blob/782917c7ad2a615ad9b31c2710bb3757416376c7/lib/src/discovery.dart#L90
It uses the class BroadcastProtocol... and there it gets too complicated for me.

Comment: We need a lot more data here.  What calls are you making to find devices?  What ones are failing that succeed in the working version?  What's the actual code?

Comment: By default apps are not allowed to TK "clear text traffic" which means non HTTPS. Not sure if UDP is also considered as clear text protocol. If it works after allowing clear text protocols you got the problem source.